# Encoding non-latin characters while doing auto-text to columns to csv file using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv with a # delimiter and I want to apply "text to columns" for it using python.
It works with a latin characters, but it doesn't with a non-latin.
I was trying to use unicodecsv package on 12.csv,
[image: 12.csv]
 got no error, but when I open an output  file out2.csv, I see a question mark.
[image: out2.csv]

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unicodecsv as csv
with open('12.csv', 'r') as csvfile, open('out2.csv','wb') as csvfileout:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='#',encoding='cp1251')
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfileout,delimiter=';',encoding='utf-8')
    spamwriter.writerows(spamreader)
```

Could you please help me what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf-8-sig` for the output encoding.  Excel likes a UTF-8-encoded file to start with a byte order mark (BOM); otherwise, it assumes the default ANSI encoding (Windows-1251, in your case).  If you'd opened the file in a tool like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) that is better at detecting the encoding, you would see that your original attempt was written correctly in UTF-8, it just didn't have the BOM.

Comment: "Doesn't work" how?  I used your exact example and made only that change and it worked fine.   Provide a reproducible example with actual data files.  I had to guess At an input file because you only posted pictures. I saved it as CP 1251.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're actually right. It works, if I open it in Notepad++, save with utf-8 with bom encoding, use utf-8-sig for the output encoding. But it seems like I have to do it every time when I want to split it automatically...And I have a lot of csv files.

Comment: @S3xCodeandRocknRoll What are you opening and re-encoding in Notepad++?  Python can read and write any encoding so you still have something that can be fixed.

Comment: A csv file. And that's what a problem is. I'm trying to modify my code, but stil have some problems.

Comment: @S3xCodeandRocknRoll Edit your question with additional details.